# Which doubly stochastic matrices can be written as products of pairwise averaging matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

A matrix $A$ is called doubly stochastic if its entries are nonnegative, and if all of its rows and columns add up to $1$. A subset of doubly stochastic matrices is the set of pairwise averaging matrices which move two components of a vector closer to their average. More precisely, a pairwise averaging matrix $P_{i,j,\alpha}$ is defined by stipulating that $y=P_{i,j,\alpha}x$ is 
$$ y_i = (1-\alpha) x_i + \alpha x_j$$
$$ y_j = \alpha x_i + (1-\alpha) x_j$$
$$ y_k = x_k ~~{\rm for~ all }~ k \neq i,j~,$$ where $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

My question is: can every doubly stochastic matrix be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices?

If the answer is no, I would like to know if its possible to characterize the doubly stochastic matrices which can be written this way.

**Update:** I just realized that the answer is no. Here is a sketch of the proof. Pick any $3 \times 3$ doubly stochastic matrix matrix $A$ with $A_{23}=A_{32}=0$. If $A$ can be written as the product of pairwise averages, the pairwise average matrices $P_{2,3,\alpha}$ never appear in the product, since they result in setting the $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ entries to 
positive numbers, which remain positive after any more applications of pairwise averages. So the product must only use $P_{1,2,\alpha}$ or $P_{1,3,\alpha}$. But one can see that no matter in what order one applies these matrices, at least one of $A_{23}$ or $A_{32}$ will be set to a positive number. For example, if we average 1 and 2 first and then 1 and 3, then $A_{32}$ will be nonzero.

My second question is still unanswered: is it possible to characterize the matrices which are products of pairwise averages?

Comment: As a positive result, the doubly stochastic $n\times n$ matrices where all the entries are $1/n$ can be written as the product of pairwise averaging matrices. https://mathoverflow.net/a/396795/22277

Comment: Let $F$ denote the set of all products of pairwise averaging matrices. Then $F$ is clearly an $F_{\sigma}$-set. Is $F$ a closed set? More generally, for all $n$ is there some $m$ such that every element in $F$ is the product of $m$ many pairwise averaging matrices?

Comment: Let $N_{n}$ be the matrix where all entries are $1/n$. Then does there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $N_{n}$ such that if $A\in U$, and $A$ is doubly stochastic, then $A$ is the product of pairwise averaging matrices?

Answer (score 6):

This question has been studied here (but no characterization is given)

Marcus, Marvin; Kidman, Kent; Sandy, Markus.
Products of elementary doubly stochastic matrices.
Linear and Multilinear Algebra 15 (1984), no. 3-4, 331–340.

Note also that if we consider the family of matrices with rows and columns adding up to 1 (but allow negative entries) and $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$, the corresponding result is true, see

Johnsen, E. C.
Essentially doubly stochastic matrices. III. Products of elementary matrices.
Linear and Multilinear Algebra 1 (1973), no. 1, 33–45.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too difficult to characterize all matrices that are products of pairwise averaging matrices, so it is probably a good idea to try to solve an easier problem (at least computationally) in a quotient monoid in order to obtain and compute many counterexamples.

Let $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $f\in S_{n}$, then let $\rho_{f}$ denote the permutation matrix $(\delta_{f(i),j})_{i,j}$ that corresponds to the permutation $f$. Suppose that $A\subseteq[n]\times[n]$. Then we say that $A$ is an $n\times n$-multipermutation if $A$ is the union of permutations. Let $M_{n}$ be the set of all $n\times n$-multipermutations.
Let $V_{n}=P([n]^{2})$, and define a composition operation in $V_{n}$ by $$A\circ B=\{(x,z)|\exists y,(x,y)\in B,(y,z)\in A\}.$$ Let $DS_{n}$ be the set of all doubly stochastic matrices. Define a mapping $\phi:DS_{n}\rightarrow M_{n}$ by letting $\phi((a_{i,j})_{i,j})=\{(i,j)\mid a_{i,j}>0\}$. Then $\phi$ is a surjective monoid anti-homomorphism (i.e. $\phi(BA)=\phi(A)\circ\phi(B)$ for doubly stochastic $A,B$, and $\phi$ preserves the identity).

Let $B_{n}$ be the submonoid of $M_{n}$ generated by elements of the form
$f\cup g$ for some $f,g\in S_{n}$. Then $R\in B_{n}$ if and only if $R=\phi(A)$ for some matrix $A$ that can be factored as a product of pairwise averaging matrices.
Therefore, if we can show that $\phi(A)\not\in B_{n}$, then we know that
$A$ cannot be factored as a product of pairwise averaging matrices.

Now, each element in $B_{n}$ can be put into the form $(1\cup f_{1})\circ\dots\circ(1\cup f_{r})\circ g$ or in the form
$u\circ (1\cup v_{1})\circ\dots\circ(1\cup v_{r})$. If we define $B_{n}^{\sharp}$ to be the submonoid of $B_{n}$ generated by the elements of the form $1\cup f$, then $B_{n}$ can be thought of as a sort of semidirect product of the permutation group $S_{n}$ and the monoid $B_{n}^{\sharp}$. In fact, if we define a monoid operation $*$ on $V_{n}\times S_{n}$ by letting $(R,f)*(S,g)=(RfSf^{-1},fg)$, and we define a monoid homomorphism $\Gamma:V_{n}\times S_{n}\rightarrow V_{n}$ by letting
$\Gamma(R,f)=Rf$, then $B_{n}=\Gamma[B_{n}^{\sharp}\times S_{n}]$.

Let $D_{n}=\{(R,(R\circ(1\cup f)))\mid R\in V,f\in S_{n}\}$. Then $G_{n}=(V_{n},D_{n})$ is an acyclic graph, so we can partially order $V_{n}$ by letting $f\leq g$ if and only if there is a directed path from $f$ to $g$. Furthermore, the partial ordering $\leq$ is compatible with $\subseteq$ since if $f\leq g$, then $f\subseteq g$ (this is useful since $\leq$ is difficult to compute, but $\subseteq$ is easy to compute). Observe that $R$ belongs to $B_{n}$ if and only if there exists some path from some permutation $f$ to $R$ in $(V_{n},D_{n})$. Define $\downarrow R=\{S\in V_{n}\mid S\subseteq R\}$. Since every path from $f$ to $R$ only goes through nodes in the set $\downarrow R$, we can restrict our path finding algorithm to induced subgraph whose nodes are precisely the elements in $\downarrow R$. Therefore, $R\in B_{n}$ if and only if there is some permutation $f$ and a path from $f$ to $R$ in the induced subgraph $G_{n}[\downarrow R]$.

Now, observe that $$N_{G_{n}[\downarrow S]}(R)=\{R\circ(1\cup f)\mid f\in S_{n},R\circ(1\cup f)\subseteq S\}=\{R\circ(1\cup f)\mid f\in S_{n},R\circ f\subseteq S\}.$$ Therefore, to calculate, $N_{G_{n}[\downarrow S]}(R)$, it suffices to find all permutations $f\in S_{n}$ such that $R\circ f\subseteq S$. However, if we define
$T_{y}=\{z\in[n]\mid\forall x,(x,y)\in R\rightarrow(x,z)\in S\}$, then
$R\circ f\subseteq S$ if and only if $f(y)\in T_{y}$ for all $y\in[n]$. Therefore, the problem of finding the elements in $N_{G_{n}[\downarrow S]}(R)$ reduces to the problem of finding all perfect matchings in bipartite graphs. However, according to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893965994900450), the problem of finding all perfect matchings in a bipartite graph takes $O(c(n+m)+n^{5/2})$ computational effort and $O(nm)$ memory where $n$ is the number of vertices, $m$ is the number of edges, and $c$ is the number of perfect matchings in the bipartite graph. However, I am not convinced that finding all bijections $f$ with $R\circ f\subseteq S$ is the best strategy for
computing $N_{G_{n}[\downarrow S]}(R)$ since there may be many more permutations $f$
with $R\circ f\subseteq S$ than elements in $N_{G_{n}[\downarrow S]}(R)$.

**An enhanced graph**

Define a graph $G_{n,S}=(V_{n,S},E_{n,S})$ where

1. $V_{n,S}$ consists of tuples $(P,A,B,Q)$ such that $|A|=|B|$ and
   $Q\subseteq R\cap(B^{c}\times[n])$.
2. $E_{n,S}$ consists of the edges of the following forms

   i. $((P,[n],[n],\emptyset),(P,\emptyset,\emptyset,P))\in E_{n,S}$

   ii. Suppose that $A\subseteq[n],B\subseteq[n]$, and $a\in A^{c},b\in B^{c}$. Then $$((P,A,B,Q),(P\cup(Q\circ\{(a,b)\}),A\cup\{a\},B\cup\{b\},Q\setminus(\{b\}\times[n])))\in E_{n,S}$$ such that
   $P\cup(Q\circ\{(a,b)\})\subseteq S$.

Suppose that $f$ is a permutation. Then there is a directed path from
$(f,\emptyset,\emptyset,f)$ to $(P,A,B,Q)$ if and only if there are
$g_{1},\dots,g_{r}$ such that if $R=f\circ(1\cup g_{1})\circ\dots\circ(1\cup g_{r})$, then there is a some bijection
$h:A\rightarrow B$ such that $P=R\cup(R\circ h)$ and $Q=R\cap(B^{c}\times[n])$. Therefore, $S\in B_{n}$ if and only if there is a path from $(f,\emptyset,\emptyset,f)$ to $(S,\emptyset,\emptyset,S)$ for some permutation $f$ with $f\subseteq S$.

Therefore, one can determine whether $S\in B_{n}$ by using a path-finding algorithm. However, our path finding algorithm will probably not be very efficient at this point, so let us reduce the number of edges from $(f,\emptyset,\emptyset,f)$ to $(S,\emptyset,\emptyset,S)$ in order to improve efficiency. We say that a subset $E\subseteq E_{n,S}$ is traversable if $E$ contains each edge of the form
$((P,[n],[n],\emptyset),(P,\emptyset,\emptyset,P))$ and where if
$(P,A,B,Q)\in V_{n,S}$ and $A\neq[n]$ and $h:A^{c}\rightarrow B^{c}$ is bijective, then there are $a\in A^{c},b\in B^{c}$ with $b=h(a)$ and where
$$((P,A,B,Q),(P\cup(Q\circ\{(a,b)\}),A\cup\{a\},B\cup\{b\},Q\setminus(\{b\}\times[n])))\in E.$$

Observe that if $E$ is traverable, then $S\in B_{n}$ if and only if there is some path from $(f,\emptyset,\emptyset,f)$ to $(S,\emptyset,\emptyset,S)$ in the directed graph $(V_{n,S},E)$, so a path finding algorithm may be used to determine whether $S\in B_{n}$ or not.

**Code**

Here is the code in GAP for determining whether $R\in B_{n}$. I have made no attempt to optimize this code.

```
allperms:=function(x) 
local list,n,table,i,newtable,j; 
n:=Length(x); table:=[[]]; 
for i in [1..n] do 
newtable:=[]; 
for list in table do 
for j in [1..n] do
if j in list then continue; fi;
if x[i][j]=1 then Add(newtable,Concatenation(list,[j])); fi; 
od; od; 
table:=newtable; od; 
return table; end;

implicator:=function(x,y) 
local n,z,i,j,k; 
n:=Length(x); z:=x*0; 
for i in [1..n] do for j in [1..n] do 
z[i][j]:=1; 
for k in [1..n] do if y[k][j]=0 and x[k][i]=1 then z[i][j]:=0; break; fi; 
od; od; od; 
return z; end;

neighbors:=function(x,y) 
local list,n,xx,z,perms,output,i,j; 
n:=Length(x); z:=implicator(x,y); perms:=allperms(z); output:=[]; 
for list in perms do 
xx:=StructuralCopy(x); 
for i in [1..n] do for j in [1..n] do 
if x[i][j]=1 then xx[i][list[j]]:=1; fi; 
od; od; 
Add(output,xx); 
od; 
return output; end;

size:=function(x) return Sum(List(x,Sum)); end;

test:=function(y) 
local a,perms,xx,n,s,i,j,tar,table,har,bb,qq; 
n:=Length(y); s:=size(y); perms:=allperms(y); tar:=NewDictionary(true,true); table:=[]; 

for a in perms do xx:=y*0; 
for i in [1..n] do xx[i][a[i]]:=1; od; 
Add(table,xx); AddDictionary(tar,xx,true); 
od; 

while Length(table)>0 do 
qq:=Remove(table); har:=neighbors(qq,y); 
for bb in har do if size(bb)=s then return true; fi; if not (LookupDictionary(tar,bb)=true) then AddDictionary(tar,bb,true); Add(table,bb); fi; od;
od; 
return false; 
end;
```

**More code**

Here is the code that finds a path in the graph $(V_{n,S},E)$ for some traverable set $E$.

```
newnode:=function(quadruple) local PP; PP:=quadruple[1]; return [PP,[],[],PP]; end;

testquad:=function(quadruple,pair,y) local a,b,P,Q,A,B,n,i; a:=pair[1]; b:=pair[2]; P:=quadruple[1]; A:=quadruple[2]; B:=quadruple[3]; Q:=quadruple[4]; n:=Length(P); 
for i in [1..n] do if Q[b][i]=1 and y[a][i]=0 then return false; fi; od; 
return true; end;

newpairzero:=function(n,zero,one) local m,l,lar,mar; m:=Length(zero); lar:=Difference([1..n],zero); mar:=Difference([1..n],one); l:=Minimum(lar); m:=Minimum(mar); return List(mar,v->[l,v]); end;

newpairone:=function(n,zero,one) local m,l,lar,mar; m:=Length(zero); lar:=Difference([1..n],zero); mar:=Difference([1..n],one); l:=Minimum(lar); m:=Minimum(mar); return List(lar,v->[v,m]); end;

extendpair:=function(quadruple,pair) local a,b,P,Q,A,B,n,i,AA,BB,PP,QQ; a:=pair[1]; b:=pair[2]; P:=quadruple[1]; A:=quadruple[2]; B:=quadruple[3]; Q:=quadruple[4]; n:=Length(P); QQ:=StructuralCopy(Q); AA:=Concatenation(A,[a]); BB:=Concatenation(B,[b]); Sort(AA); Sort(BB); PP:=StructuralCopy(P); 
for i in [1..n] do PP[a][i]:=Maximum(QQ[b][i],PP[a][i]); QQ[b][i]:=0; od; 
return [PP,AA,BB,QQ]; end;

test:=function(y) local P,Q,pair,list,n,tar,table,xx,i,j,A,B,quadruple; n:=Length(y); tar:=NewDictionary(true,true); table:=[]; xx:=[]; 
for i in [1..n] do xx[i]:=[]; for j in [1..n] do xx[i][j]:=0; od; xx[i][i]:=1; od; 
Add(table,[xx,[],[],xx]); 
while Length(table)>0 do quadruple:=Remove(table); 
 if not LookupDictionary(tar,quadruple)=fail then continue; fi; 
 AddDictionary(tar,quadruple,true); P:=quadruple[1]; A:=quadruple[2]; 
 B:=quadruple[3]; Q:=quadruple[4]; 
 if Length(A)=n then if P=y then return true; fi; 
 Add(table,newnode(quadruple)); else list:=newpairzero(n,A,B); 
 for pair in list do if testquad(quadruple,pair,y) then 
 Add(table,extendpair(quadruple,pair)); fi; od; 
 fi; 
od; 

return false; end;
```

**Empirical observations**

I ran the above algorithm to determine whether elements belonged to $B_{n}$, and most elements in $M_{n}$ that I have tested do not belong to $B_{n}$. In fact, in most cases, elements of the form $f\cup g\cup h$ where $f,g,h\in S_{n}$ do not belong to $B_{n}$, so most stochastic matrices of the form $\frac{1}{3}(\rho_{f}+\rho_{g}+\rho_{h})$ cannot be written as the product pairwise averaging matrices.

I will probably add details and improve this answer some time later in order to improve the algorithm for determining whether an element $R\in V_{n}$ belongs to $B_{n}$ or not.

**Singular matrices**

Suppose that $f$ is a permutation that can be written as the composition of $r$ disjoint cycles of lengths $k_{1},\dots,k_{r}$.

Then $$\text{Det}(t\cdot 1_{n}+(1-t)\rho_{f})=\prod_{j=1}^{r}[t^{k_{j}}+(t-1)^{k_{j}}].$$ In particular, $t\cdot 1_{n}+(1-t)\rho_{f}$ is non-singular if and only if $t=1/2$, and if $t=1/2$, then
$\text{Rank}(t\cdot 1_{n}+(1-t)\rho_{f})$ is the number of odd cycles in the permutation $f$.

If $R\in B_{n}$, then let $N(R)$ be the supremum of all sums $m_{1}+\dots+m_{r}$ such that $R=f(1+g_{1})\dots(1+g_{r})$ and when $g_{i}$ is written as a disjoint composition of cycles, $m_{i}$ of those cycles are odd. If $R\not\in B_{n}$, then set $N(R)=\infty$. We can adjust our algorithm for determining whether $R\in B_{n}$ or not so that it calculates the value $N(R)$ as well.

Then observe that if $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix that can be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices, then $\text{Null}(A)\leq N(\phi(A))$. Therefore, if $\text{Null}(A)>N(\phi(A))$, then we know that $A$ cannot be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices.

**Doubly stochastic matrices near a permutation matrix**

The problem of determining whether $R\in B_{n}^{\sharp}$ or not is easier to solve than the problem of determining whether $R\in B_{n}$ since for $B_{n}^{\sharp}$, the path finding algorithm starts with a single vertex, namely $(1,\emptyset,\emptyset,1)$ instead of many vertices. Fortunately, the problem of determining whether a set belongs to $B_{n}^{\sharp}$ helps us prove that certain doubly stochastic matrices cannot be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices.

If $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix that is too close to a permutation matrix $\rho_{f}$, and $A$ can be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices, then we know that $A$ can be put in the form
$A=\rho_{f}(t_{1}I_{n}+(1-t_{1})\rho_{g_{1}})\dots(t_{r}I_{n}+(1-t_{r})\rho_{g_{r}})$ for constants $t_{1},\dots,t_{r}\in(0,1)$ where the constants $t_{1},\dots,t_{r}$ are near $1$. Let us make this intuition precise.

> Theorem: Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on the vector space of all $n\times n$-matrices. Let $$M=\max_{f\in S_{n}}\|\rho_{f}\|,$$ and let
> $$N=\min_{f\in S_{n}\setminus\{1\}}\|I_{n}-\rho_{f}\|.$$ Then whenever
> $A$ is the product of pairwise averaging matrices, then
>
> 1. $$A=(t_{1}I_{n}+(1-t_{1})\rho_{f_{1}})\cdots(t_{r}I_{n}+(1-t_{r})\rho_{f_{r}})$$
>    where $\min(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})\geq 1/2$
>
> or
>
> 2. $$\|A-I_{n}\|\geq N-2M(1-|\det(A)|).$$

Proof: Suppose that $f$ is a permutation that can be decomposed into disjoint cycles of lengths $k_{1},\dots,k_{r}$. Observe that
$$|\det(tI_{n}+(1-t)\rho_{f})|=\prod_{j=1}^{r}|t^{k_{j}}+(t-1)^{k_{j}}|
\leq|t^{k_{1}}+(t-1)^{k_{1}}|$$
$$\leq t^{k_{1}}+(1-t)^{k_{1}}\leq t^{2}+(1-t)^{2}\leq\frac{1}{2}+|t-\frac{1}{2}|.$$

Now, suppose that $A$ is the product of pairwise averaging matrices. Then without loss of generality, there are $t_{1},\dots,t_{r}$ such that $\min(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})\geq\frac{1}{2}$ along with permutations $f,g_{1},\dots,g_{r}$ where
$$A=\rho_{f}(t_{1}I_{n}+(1-t_{1})\rho_{g_{1}})\dots(t_{r}I_{n}+(1-t_{r})\rho_{g_{r}})$$.

In this case, we have $\det(A)\leq t_{1}\dots t_{r}$.

Now, $$\|A-\rho_{f}\|\leq\|A-\rho_{f}t_{1}\dots t_{r}I_{n}\|+\|\rho_{f}t_{1}\dots t_{r}I_{n}-\rho_{f}\|$$
$$\leq(1-t_{1}\dots t_{r})M+(1-t_{1}\dots t_{r})M\leq 2M(1-t_{1}\dots t_{r})\leq 2M(1-\det(A)).$$

Therefore, $$\|A-I_{n}\|\geq\|I-\rho_{f}\|-\|A-\rho_{f}\|\geq N-2M(1-\det(A)).$$ Q.E.D.

Observe that $M=\max\{\|A\|:\text{$A$ is doubly stochastic}\}$. Furthermore, $\|N\|\leq\|I_{n}\|+M\leq 2M$. If the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is submultiplicative ($\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\cdot\|B\|$ for all $A,B$), then $M=\|I\|=I_{n},\|N\|\leq 2$.

> Theorem: Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on the set of all $n\times
>  n$-matrices. Let $$M=\max_{f\in S_{n}}\|\rho_{f}\|,N=\min_{f\in
>  S_{n}\setminus\{1\}}\|I_{n}-\rho_{f}\|.$$
>
> Suppose that $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix. If $\phi(A)\not\in
>  B_{n}^{\sharp}$, and $$|A-I_{n}|<N-2M(1-\det(A)),$$ then $A$ cannot be
> written as the product of pairwise averaging matrices.

**Argument from dimensionality**

Suppose that $R\in B_{n}$. Then let $T_{R}$ be the vector subspace of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all matrices $(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ such that
$\{(i,j)\mid a_{i,j}\neq 0\}\subseteq R$ and where $\sum_{k}a_{i,k}=0$ for each $i\in[n]$ and where $\sum_{k}a_{k,j}=0$ for each $i\in[n]$. Observe that $\dim(T_{R})\geq|R|-2n$.

Then whenever $\phi(A)=R$, there is an open subset $U$ of $T_{R}$ such that
$A+B$ is doubly stochastic for each $B\in U$.

Proposition: Suppose that $R\subseteq[n]^{2}$, $R$ is the union of permutations, but $R$ cannot be put into the form $R=f(1\cup f_{1})\dots(1\cup f_{r})$ where $f_{1},\dots,f_{r}$ are non-identity permutations and $f$ is a permutation, and where $r\geq\dim(T_{R})$. Then there is a doubly stochastic matrix $A$ with $\phi(A)=R$ but where
$A$ cannot be written as a product of doubly stochastic matrices.

Proof: Simply observe that the dimension of the set of all doubly stochastic matrices $A$ with $\phi(A)=R$ is $\dim(T_{R})$ while the dimension of the set of all products of pairwise averaging matrices $A$ with $\phi(A)=R$ is at most $\dim(T_{R})-1$. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Let $DS_{n}$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ doubly stochastic matrices. Let $F_{n}$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices that can be written as products of pairwise averaging matrices. Then I claim that $F_{n}\subseteq\overline{F_{n}^{\circ}}$ where the interior and closure are taken in the set $DS_{n}$. Therefore, $F_{n}\setminus F_{n}^{\circ}$ is nowhere dense in $DS_{n}$. ​In particular, if $F_{n}$ is closed, then $F_{n}$ must be regular closed. I still do not know whether $F_{n}$ is a closed set of not.

Let $DS_{n}^{\sharp}$ be the collection of all $n\times n$ matrices with real-valued entries where the sum of each row is $1$ and the sum of each column is also $1$. Let
$T_{n}$ be the collection of all $n\times n$ matrices with real-valued entries where the sum of each row is $0$ and the sum of each column is also $0$. In other words,
$DS_{n}^{\sharp}$ is the set of all generalized doubly stochastic matrices, and
$T_{n}$ is the tangent space of each point of $DS_{n}^{\sharp}$.

We observe that $\dim(T_{n})=(n-1)^{2}$, and $T_{n}$ is generated by elements of the form $\rho(f)-I_{n}$ where $\rho(f)$ is the permutation matrix that corresponds to the permutation $f$. Let $r=n^{2}$. There are permutations $f_{1},\dots,f_{r}$ where $\rho(f_{1})-I_{n},\dots,\rho(f_{r})-I_{n}$ is a basis for $T_{n}$.

I claim that whenever $A\in F_{n}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is some open subset $U\subseteq DS_{n}^{\sharp}$ and some $B\in\overline{U}$ with $\|A-B\|<\epsilon$.

Suppose that $A\in F_{n}$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is some invertible matrix
$B\in F_{n}$ with $\|A-B\|<\epsilon$.

Define a function $C:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow DS_{n}^{\sharp}$ by letting
$$C(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})=B((1-t_{1})I_{n}+t_{1}\rho(f_{1}))\dots((1-t_{r})I_{n}+t_{r}\rho(f_{r})).$$

Now, if $1\leq i\leq n$, then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{i}}C(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})|_{(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})=0}=B\cdot(\rho(f_{i})-I_{n}).$$

Now, since $B$ is invertible, it turns out that the vectors of the form
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{i}}C(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})|_{(t_{1},\dots,t_{r})=0}=B\cdot(\rho(f_{i})-I_{n})$$ form a basis of the tangent space $T_{n}$. Therefore, by the inverse function theorem, we can conclude that there is an open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $(0,\dots,0)\in U$ such that if $V=C[U]$, then $C$ maps $U$ diffeomorphically onto $V$ and where $V$ is an open subset of $DS_{n}^{\sharp}$. Observe furthermore that $B=C(0,\dots,0)$. Let $$U_{1}=\{(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\in U\mid\max(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})<1,\min(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})>0\}.$$ Then there is some open $V_{1}\subseteq V$ such that $C$ maps $U_{1}$ diffeomorphically onto $V_{1}$ and where $B\in\overline{V_{1}}$. However, $V_{1}$ is an open subset of $DS_{n}^{\sharp}$ consisting solely of products of pairwise averaging matrices.