# Is every nearly rank-1 doubly stochastic matrix a product of pairwise averaging matrices?

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

A doubly stochastic matrix is a square matrix with non-negative real entries where the sum of each row is $1$ and the sum of each column is $1$. A pairwise averaging matrix is a matrix of the form $tA+(1-t)B$ where $t\in[0,1]$ and $A,B$ are permutation matrices (recall that the permutation matrices are precisely the doubly stochastic matrices where each entry is either a $0$ or a $1$; clearly the $n\times n$-permutation matrices can be put into a one-to-one-correspondence with permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$)

Let $N_{n}$ be the $n\times n$-matrix where each entry is $1/n$. Does there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $N_{n}$ where if $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix with $A\in U$, then $A$ can be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices?

1. There are plenty of examples of doubly stochastic matrices that cannot be written as products of pairwise averaging matrices. See [this similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40683/22277) for more details.
2. $N_{n}$ itself can be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices. [Here is one way to get factorizations.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/396795/22277)
3. Let $DS_{n}$ denote the space of all $n\times n$-doubly stochastic matrices. Let $F_{n}$ be the set of all matrices that can be written as a product of pairwise averaging matrices. Then
   $F_{n}\subseteq\overline{F_{n}^{\circ}}$ where the closure and interior are taken in the space $DS_{n}$. [Here is a proof.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/398124/22277) I have tried unsuccessfully to extend this proof to show that $N_{n}\in F_{n}^{\circ}$.