# Is every nearly rank 1 doubly stochastic superoperator the product of pairwise averagings of unitary channels?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

Suppose that $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. Let $L(\mathcal{X})$ denote the collection of all linear mappings from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{X}$. We say that a linear mapping $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ is trace preserving if $\text{Tr}(T(A))=\text{Tr}(A)$ for each $A\in L(\mathcal{X})$, and we say that $T$ is unital if $T(1_{\mathcal{X}})=1_{\mathcal{X}}$. We say that $A\in L(\mathcal{X})$ is positive if $A=BB^{*}$ for some $B\in L(\mathcal{X})$. We say that a linear mapping $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ is positive if $T(A)$ is positive whenever $A\in L(\mathcal{X})$ is positive, and we say that $T$ is completely positive if whenever $\mathcal{Z}$ is a finite dimensional complex inner product space, then $T\otimes 1_{L(\mathcal{Z})}:L(\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Z})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Z})$ is positive. A doubly stochastic superoperator is a completely positive, trace preserving, and unital linear mapping $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ (doubly stochastic superoperators are also called unital channels). See the book The Theory of Quantum Information by John Watrous for more context on doubly stochastic superoperators.

Example: Let $\Omega_{\mathcal{X}}:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ be the mapping where
$\Omega_{\mathcal{X}}(A)=\frac{1}{\dim(\mathcal{X})}\cdot\text{Tr}(A)\cdot 1_{\mathcal{X}}$ for each $A$. Then $\Omega_{\mathcal{X}}$ is a doubly stochastic superoperator known as the completely depolarizing channel. The completely depolarizing channel is the only kind of rank-1 doubly stochastic superoperator.

If $U\in L(\mathcal{X})$ is unitary, then the mapping $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ defined by letting $T(A)=UAU^{*}$ is a doubly stochastic superoperator known as a unitary channel. If $0\leq t\leq 1$ and $U,V\in L(\mathcal{X})$ are unitary, then we say that the operator $T$ defined by $T(A)=t\cdot UAU^{*}+(1-t)\cdot VAV^{*}$ shall be called a pairwise averaging of unitary channels.

We say that a mapping $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ is mixed unitary if there are $t_{1},\dots,t_{n}\geq 0$ with $t_{1}+\dots+t_{n}=1$ and unitary $U_{1},\dots,U_{n}$ where
$T(A)=t_{1}\cdot U_{1}AU_{1}^{*}+\dots+t_{n}\cdot U_{n}AU_{n}^{*}$ for all $A\in L(\mathcal{X})$. Every mixed unitary channel is always a doubly stochastic superoperator. Not every mixed unitary channel is a doubly stochastic superoperator, but mixed unitary channels are closely related to doubly stochastic superoperators.

Theorem: (John Watrous [link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/Papers/MixingDoublyStochasticChannels.pdf)) If $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ is doubly stochastic, and $0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{\dim(\mathcal{X})^{2}-1}$, then $t\cdot T+(1-t)\Omega_{\mathcal{X}}$ is mixed unitary.

Suppose that $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. Then does there necessarily exist some $\epsilon>0$ where if $0\leq t<\epsilon$ and $T:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{X})$ is a doubly stochastic superoperator, then $t\cdot T+(1-t)\Omega_{\mathcal{X}}=T_{1}\dots T_{n}$ for some pairwise averagings of unitary channels $T_{1},\dots,T_{n}$?

This is a follow up of [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40683/22277) and [my other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40683/22277).